# Issue with Dotenv module running Laravel Dusk after upgrade to Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

After **upgrading** to **Laravel 5.8** I have an issue running **Laravel Dusk**.

> Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() must be an instance of 
>   Dotenv\Loader, string given, called in 
>   .../vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Console/DuskCommand.php on line 204

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Dusk 5.0.1: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/CHANGELOG.md